# Windows 10 - Unable to associate via "open with" for cmd files via GUI

Tags: windows, windows-10

After a recent update, `.cmd` files are not associated with my text editor. I liked having it set since I need to edit them a lot here at work, and prefer not to have double click run them since they all need options.

Right clicking on most file types correctly brings up the `Open with` context menu. It does not for `.cmd` files. How do I get it to appear?

The file association control panel `Choose default apps by file type` is no help. When I try to select a default for any file type, it says nothing is installed, and I have to go to the App Store. I don't want to because I have something installed already. The problem appears to be that it's a program from a few years ago, not an "app", so it has no place in the modern world.

I have tried browsing to `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Default Programs` but the top 2 options both bring me to that same screen.

I did manage to work around this by using `regedit` and browsing to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\cmdfile\shell\open\command` however that's not an option I'd be comfortable suggesting to all users. Is it possible to do this through the UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a GUI method that is not one of those that you have already listed.

You may find several posts on our site that also discuss the limitations that
Windows 10 has created for default type-handlers, which often lead to registry
update as the only solution.

You do not need to ask your users to go into `regedit`.
You may export your registry settings to a `.reg` file and distribute that,
or alternatively distribute a `.bat` file with the appropriate
[REG commands](https://ss64.com/nt/reg.html).